# NSObject as a returned type

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, return-type, nsobject

I am about to merge my part of a project (written in `Objective-C)` with another one (written in `Swift`). Is it possible to have `NSObject` as a returned type (and then, subsequently, to refer to functions via `[nsObjectVariableName functionName]`?

Comment: Yes. `import Foundation` is all that is required. However you would not use the syntax `[nsObjectVariableName functionName]`, rather use `nsObjectVariableName.functionName`